# itunes movie trailers gridview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, gridview, epg

I'm trying to reproduce a gridview for a landscape only iPad app.

I've tried a few know Gridviews such as AQGridview or GMGridView but it doesn't fit since it's not a "traditional" gridview (it is for an epg so the elements are not of the same size - depending on their duration).

What I would like to achieve should be more like the [iTunes Movie Trailers app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-movie-trailers/id471966214).

I was wondering if you know any library (free & open source, if possible) that could help me to achieve this.

Last one I've seen is [NGVaryingGridView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ngvaryinggridview) which sounds promising but it doesn't seem to be optimized (try to rotate it just for fun).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS 6, Apple added `UICollectionView`. Using a `UIFlowLayout` you can do exactly what you want. It's pretty neat. The only downside is that it's not available in iOS 5.

Comment: Yes I saw that, can't wait to try it out. But I'm looking for a solution available for iOS 4.0+

Comment: Maybe you can try using a traditional grid view, like GMGridView and adjust the content in each cell to keep it's proportions. This way the elements wouldn't have to be the same size. And maybe have a look at [cocoaobjects.com](http://cocoaobjects.com/) or [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/).